# Using : on a class and interface

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering about the usage of `:` symbol or operator, how you want to call it, in the following cases:

**First case**

```
public class Foo : IBar
{
     ...
}
```

In this case **class** `Foo` implements **interface** `IBar`, correct?

---

**Second case**

```
interface Foo : IBar
{
     ...
}
```

In this case, is **interface** `Foo` implementing the **interface** `IBar`, or extending it?

Comment: "is interface Foo implementing the interface IBar, or extending it?" How does this effect your understanding? Is this just academic interest or do you have a **specific** problem to solve?

Comment: @HimBromBeere, just academic interesnt.

Comment: Then the answer is: only **classes** (and structs) can implement interfaces. However interfaces can extend other interfaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this colon mean in this C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656522/what-does-this-colon-mean-in-this-c-sharp-code)

Comment: An implementation of an interface is always in a class(or struct). So interfaces can just be extended by other interfaces. You can create an `abstract` class that (partially) implements an interface or add other abstract methods/properties. Then this class implements and extends that interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be argued that **both** are a case of extending:

- In case of an **interface**, it extends the other interface(s) with new *definitions* of properties and/or methods (if anything is added at all).
- In case of a **class**, it extends the interface(s) with *implementations* of properties and/or methods (in case of an abstract class, the implementations could still be abstract).

This is by no means official, I just thought it would be a nice way to describe it.

More common however, at least in the .C#/NET world, is to call it "inheriting" when there are interfaces on both sides of the colon, "implementing" when there is a class is on the left + an interface on the right, and "inheriting" again when there are classes on both sides.

Sources:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Very nice idea of how to describe the two cases. Also + for leaving additional sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you go by the intermediate language (IL) C# compiles into, the term "extends" is used when a class inherits from another class. The term "implements" is used when a class inherits an interface and when an interface inherits another interface.

C#:

```
namespace CSharpConsoleApp
{
    public interface InterfaceA
    {
    }

    public interface InterfaceB : InterfaceA
    {
    }

    public class ClassA
    {
    }

    public class ClassB : ClassA, InterfaceB
    {
    }
}
```

IL (abridged):

```
.class interface public abstract auto ansi CSharpConsoleApp.InterfaceA
{
}

.class interface public abstract auto ansi CSharpConsoleApp.InterfaceB
       implements CSharpConsoleApp.InterfaceA
{
}

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit CSharpConsoleApp.ClassA
       extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
{
  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
    // ...
  }

}

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit CSharpConsoleApp.ClassB
       extends CSharpConsoleApp.ClassA
       implements CSharpConsoleApp.InterfaceB,
                  CSharpConsoleApp.InterfaceA
{
  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
    // ...
  }

}
```

So the term "implements" would be appropriate for both of your scenarios.